# bootstrap nav-tabs + Swiper

Tags: bootstrap, tab

из трех вкладок Swiper работает нормально только в первой, в последующих же он как я понимаю не может посчитать ширину экрана. 
Подскажите кто сталкивался, как правильно решить задачу.

```
<div class="tab-conteiner">
<div class="w-container container">
    <div class="w-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-12">
            <!--<div class="tab-conteiner w-col w-col-2">-->
            <!-- Навигация -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs row" role="myTabs">
                <li class="active w-col-4"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab"
                                              data-toggle="tab"><h3>Для дома</h3></a>
                </li>
                <li class="w-col-4"><a href="#foo" aria-controls="profile" role="tab"
                                       data-toggle="tab"><h3>Для кафе</h3></a></li>
                <li class="w-col-4"><a href="#bar" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><h3>
                    Для Отдыха</h3></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Содержимое вкладок -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane  fade in active" id="home">
                    <div class="slidersection">
                        <!-- Swiper -->
                        <div class="swiper-container1">
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/slider/slider1.jpg"
                                                               alt="image01"/></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/slider/slider2.jpg"
                                                               alt="image02"/></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/slider/slider3.gif"
                                                               alt="image03"/></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-pagination1"></div>
                            <div class="swiper-button-next1"></div>
                            <div class="swiper-button-prev1"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane  " id="foo">
                    <div class="slidersection">
                        <!-- Swiper -->
                        <div class="swiper-container2">
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/slider/slider4.jpg"
                                                               alt="image01"/></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/slider/slider5.jpg"
                                                               alt="image02"/></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/slider/slider6.gif"
                                                               alt="image03"/></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-pagination2"></div>
                            <div class="swiper-button-next2"></div>
                            <div class="swiper-button-prev2"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane  in " id="bar">
                    <div class="slidersection">
                        <!-- Swiper -->
                        <div class="swiper-container3">
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/slider/slider7.jpg"
                                                               alt="image01"/></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/slider/slider8.jpg"
                                                               alt="image02"/></div>
                                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/slider/slider9.gif"
                                                               alt="image03"/></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-pagination3"></div>
                            <div class="swiper-button-next3"></div>
                            <div class="swiper-button-prev3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

инициализирую три раза

```
<script>
       var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container1', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination1',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next1',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev1',
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        centeredSlides: true,
        autoplay: null,
        autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
    });
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container2', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination2',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next2',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev2',
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        centeredSlides: true,
        autoplay: null,
        autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
    });
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container3', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination3',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next3',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev3',
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        centeredSlides: true,
        autoplay: null,
        autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
    });

});
```

Comment: Добрый вечер, можно узнать какая версия bootstrap-а?

Comment: У закрытых вкладок свойство `display:none` Из-за этого свайпер может инициализмроваться с нулевыми размерами. (Такая засада у оул-карусели, например.). Попробуйте при открытии вкладок отправлять нужному свайперу событие `resize` или переинициализировать его.

Answer (score 0):

Может подойдет вам такое решение

```css
#myTabContent{
        background-color:#fefefe;
        padding:15px;
    }
    .main{
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .swiper-slide{
        background-color:#ddd;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .swiper-text .swiper-slide{
        background-color:#ddd;
        padding: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html dir="ltr" lang="ru">
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
   
<div class="main">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="slider1-tab" href="#slider1">First</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="slider2-tab" href="#slider2">Two</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="slider3-tab" href="#slider3">Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane show active" id="slider1">
            <div class="swiper-container" id="slider1_1">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper swiper-text">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1 - 1 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2 - 1 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3 - 1 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4 - 1 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5 - 1 slider</div>
                </div>

                <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="slider2" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="swiper-container" id="slider2_1">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://bestofjs.org/logos/swiper.svg" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://bestofjs.org/logos/swiper.svg" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://bestofjs.org/logos/swiper.svg" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://bestofjs.org/logos/swiper.svg" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://bestofjs.org/logos/swiper.svg" /></div>
                </div>

                <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
              <div class="swiper-container" id="slider2_2">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper swiper-text">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1 - 2 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2 - 2 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3 - 2 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4 - 2 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5 - 2 slider</div>
                </div>

                <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="slider3" role="tabpanel">
              <div class="swiper-container" id="slider3_1">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper swiper-text">
                    <!-- Slides -->
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1 - 3 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2 - 3 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3 - 3 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4 - 3 slider</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5 - 3 slider</div>
                </div>

                <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var mySwipers = {};

function initSwiper(id,idname){ 
   
   var allslider = $(id).find('.swiper-container');
   
   $.each(allslider,function(key,val){
    var selecto = id +' #'+$(val).attr('id');
      mySwipers[idname] = new Swiper (selecto, {
          // Optional parameters
          loop: key == 0 ? true : false,
          slidesPerView: 4,
          slidesPerGroup:1,
          autoplay: {
            delay: key == 0 ? 1500 : 1000,
            disableOnInteraction: false
          },
          spaceBetween:15,
          pagination: {
            el: selecto+' .swiper-pagination',
            dynamicBullets:true,
            dynamicMainBullets:3
          },
          navigation: {
            nextEl: selecto+' .swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: selecto+' .swiper-button-prev',
          },
          on:{
            slideChange(){
                //console.log('change slide ',this.activeIndex , this.el.id);
            }
          },
            breakpoints: {
                320: {
                  slidesPerView: 1,
                  spaceBetween: 10
                },
                768: {
                  slidesPerView: 2,
                  spaceBetween: 15
                },
                1024: {
                  slidesPerView: 3,
                  spaceBetween: 15
                }
              },
            observer:true,
            observeParents:true,
            observeSlideChildren:true
        })
        
    })
    
}

    $('#myTab a').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
          
        var self = this;
        var id = $(e.target).attr('href');

        var re = /#/gi;
        var idname = id.replace(re, '');
          
        $(self).tab('show');
        initSwiper(id,idname);
       
    })

    
     initSwiper('#slider1','slider1');
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```