# Не правильно отрабатывает инициализация слайдера

Tags: javascript, tabs, swiper

При загрузке страницы я навешиваю события одного клика на ссылки табов и этим инициализирую слайдер внутри него, инициализация находится в setTimeout(), после навешивания обработчиков, тригерю клик по первому элементу и первый слайдер нормально отрабатывает(кроме того что кнопки не подключаются), а последующие клики вроде срабатывают, но кнопки так же не подключаются и когда пролистываешь его он не переключается как слайдер, типо встаёт по три в ряд, а просто проматывается как плёнка, сколько прокрутил, так и встало.

$(window).on('load', function() {

$('#common-home .oct-product-tab .nav li a').each(function() {

```
  $(this).one('click', function() {

     setTimeout(() => {

        let element = $(this).closest('.oct_nav_tabs').next('.tab-content').find('.swiper-container');

        let slider_def = element.attr('data-slides-per-view');
        let module_name = element.attr('data-module-name');
        let slider_speed = element.attr('data-slider-speed');
        let slider_autoplay = element.attr('data-slider-autoplay');
        let slider_loop = element.attr('data-slider-loop');

        let breakpointsArray = {
           600: element.attr('data-600'),
           768: element.attr('data-768'),
           992: element.attr('data-992'),
           1200: element.attr('data-1200'),
           1600: element.attr('data-1600'),
        };

        element.swiper({
           mode: 'horizontal',
           pagination: false,
           slidesPerView: slider_def,
           paginationClickable: true,
           nextButton: '.' + module_name + '-button-next',
           prevButton: '.' + module_name + '-button-prev',
           spaceBetween: 0,
           speed: slider_speed,
           autoplay: slider_autoplay,
           autoplayDisableOnInteraction: true,
           loop: slider_loop,
           breakpoints: {
              600: {
                 slidesPerView: breakpointsArray['600']
              },
              768: {
                 slidesPerView: breakpointsArray['768']
              },
              992: {
                 slidesPerView: breakpointsArray['992']
              },
              1200: {
                 slidesPerView: breakpointsArray['1200']
              },
              1600: {
                 slidesPerView: breakpointsArray['1600']
              },
           }
        });

     }, 300); 

  });
```

});

$('#common-home .oct-product-tab .nav li.active a').trigger('click');

});

Comment: `.update()`?...

Comment: Можно ли немного точнее, пожалуйста ?

Comment: отслеживаете событие клика по табам и вызываете у слайдера метода `update()` (почитайте API)

Comment: как вариант - [swiper+tabs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671636/bootstrap-nav-tabs-swiper/982723#982723)